# concatenate unique strings of variable in data.table by repeated values of another variable in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that has one column, we'll call it `country` with repeated values, and another column (`survey`) that has unique strings for each observation. I want to create a new variable that has the pasted value of all the `survey` strings for an individual country. I've done it with an index and a for loop but I'm curious if there's a quicker way to do this with some data.table syntax. MWE:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(country = c("Belgium","Belgium","Bolivia","Brazil","Brazil","Brazil"),
                      survey = c("BE01, BE03, BE04","BE05, BE07, BE11",
                            "BO11, BO13", "BR01, BR02, BR03", "BR05","BR12, BR13"))
dt[, index := seq(1, .N), by = "country"]
for(cntry in unique(dt$country)){
  tmp_ind <- max(dt[country == eval(cntry)]$index)
  dt[country == eval(cntry) & index ==1, all_surveys := survey]
  if(tmp_ind > 1) {
    for(i in 2:tmp_ind){
      dt[country == eval(cntry) & index ==i,
         all_surveys := paste0(dt[country == eval(cntry) & index == i-1, all_surveys], survey)]
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives the desired

```
> dt
   country           survey index                      all_surveys
1: Belgium BE01, BE03, BE04     1                 BE01, BE03, BE04
2: Belgium BE05, BE07, BE11     2 BE01, BE03, BE04BE05, BE07, BE11
3: Bolivia       BO11, BO13     1                       BO11, BO13
4:  Brazil BR01, BR02, BR03     1                 BR01, BR02, BR03
5:  Brazil             BR05     2             BR01, BR02, BR03BR05
6:  Brazil       BR12, BR13     3   BR01, BR02, BR03BR05BR12, BR13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved without looping

```
library(data.table)

# Create the data.table
dt <- data.table(country = c("Belgium", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil"),
                 survey = c("BE01, BE03, BE04", "BE05, BE07, BE11", "BO11, BO13", 
                            "BR01, BR02, BR03", "BR05", "BR12, BR13"))

# Create index
dt[, index := seq_len(.N), by = "country"]

# Create all_surveys
dt[, all_surveys := Reduce(function(prev, curr) paste0(prev, curr), 
                           x = survey, 
                           accumulate = TRUE), 
   by = "country"]

print(dt)
```

```
> print(dt)
   country           survey index                      all_surveys
1: Belgium BE01, BE03, BE04     1                 BE01, BE03, BE04
2: Belgium BE05, BE07, BE11     2 BE01, BE03, BE04BE05, BE07, BE11
3: Bolivia       BO11, BO13     1                       BO11, BO13
4:  Brazil BR01, BR02, BR03     1                 BR01, BR02, BR03
5:  Brazil             BR05     2             BR01, BR02, BR03BR05
6:  Brazil       BR12, BR13     3   BR01, BR02, BR03BR05BR12, BR13
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you Rodrigo! I haven't seen this before, are `prev` and `curr` default attributes within a `data.table` environment?

Comment: Great to hear that! No, prev and curr are not default attributes within a data.table environment. They are argument names that I chose for the anonymous function (an anonymous function is a function that is defined without a name) defined within the Reduce function. The Reduce function applies a function to the elements of a list or vector from left to right, so as to reduce the list or vector to a single value.

Comment: I like the use of `Reduce` here! A minor imrovement might be to use `paste0(prev, ", ", curr)`, in order to have consistent and properly reusable output. It changes `BE01, BE03, BE04BE05, BE07, BE11` to `BE01, BE03, BE04, BE05, BE07, BE11`.